# Calling load functions in correct order from constructors

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have two classes like the following:

```
class Super(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def load(self):
        # Load data from disk if available
        try:
            self.data = load_routine()
        except IOError as e:
            if e[0] == errno.ENOENT:
                pass
            else:
                raise


class Sub(Super):
    def __init__(self, arg2, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Sub, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def load(self):
        # Load files specific to superclass
        super(Sub, self).load()
        # Load data from disk if available
        try:
            self.data2 = another_different_load_routine(self.arg2)
        except IOError as e:
            if e[0] == errno.ENOENT:
                pass
            else:
                raise
```

I hope the code is clear enough, and unless I missed something this should work for both classes by using it for example like: `obj = Super(); obj.load()`.

However, I actually want the load method to be called automatically at the end of `__init__()`, but I am not sure on how to accomplish this. If I add `self.load()` at the end of `__init__()` for both classes the `load()` method of the subclass would be called twice, if try to create an instance of `Sub`, once from the superclass and once from the subclass.

If I instead put the call to `self.load()` only at the end of the init method of the superclass, it will only be called once but then the object hasn't been initialized to contain the attributes it needs for loading.

What I do want, when instantiating `Sub`, is for it to initialize all attributes in `__init__` for both super and subclass, and call `load()` for both super and subclass. Whether its in the order

`Super -> __init__()`, `Super -> load()`, `Sub -> __init__()`, `Sub -> load()`

or

`Super -> __init__()`, `Sub -> __init__()`, `Super -> load()`, `Sub -> load()`

is not important. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the combination you failed to enumerate:

```
class Super(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init super'
        if self.__class__ == Super:
            self.load()
    def load(self):
        print 'load super'

class Sub(Super):
    def __init__(self):
        # always do super first in init
        super(Sub, self).__init__()
        print 'init sub'
        self.load()
    def load(self):
        # load is essentially an extension of init
        # so you still need to call super first
        super(Sub, self).load()
        print 'load sub'

sub = Sub()
```

If you actually want to instantiate super (it's not an abstract class) you need the `if` test in it's init. Otherwise, you cannot get the in-order semantics you want with your current class structure and initialization scheme.

`Sub()` will call `Sub.__init__`, which will call `Super.__init__` (before doing anything).

Afterwards, `__init__` on `Sub` will do it's thing.

Last, `Sub.__init__` will call `Sub.load`, which will call `Super.load` (before doing anything), then do it's own work.

The "normal" way to do this would be

```
sub = Sub()
sub.load()
sup = Super()
sup.load()
```

Without the `__init__` methods calling `load` at all. This is probably what I'd recommend if you really want to call up levels in `load` as it is essentially a second set of `__init__`s.

Edit: Read the comments about the failings in the previous two versions (and see the edits to see the older one). Here is another version, using a metaclass:

```
class Loader(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if attrs.get('__init__'):
            attrs['_init'] = attrs['__init__']
            del attrs['__init__']
        if attrs.get('_init_'):
            attrs['__init__'] = lambda self: self._init_()
            attrs['_init'] = lambda self: None
        return super(Loader, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Super(object):
    __metaclass__ = Loader
    def _init_(self):
        print 'init super'
        self._init()
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        print 'load super'

class Sub(Super):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init sub'

    def load(self):
        super(Sub, self).load()
        print 'load sub'


sub = Sub()
sup = Super()
```

This has a different restriction: All subclasses can act perfectly normally, except they can't call `Sub.__init__`, by using `super().__init__()`. I think it's possible to remove this restriction but I don't see how at this second without another layer of indirection somewhere.

Comment: What if you create an instance of `Super()`?

Comment: Please note my edit that deals with `Super()` being a concrete class.

Comment: Your edited version still breaks if we have subclasses that don't need any custom initialisation so they don't override `__init__` at all.

Comment: You're right, I just change the constraint, I didn't remove it. I think that the answer is that to be done right, this call structure has to be done from outside of the class, with classmethod as you describe in your comment or with two separate calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the `__init__()` to fully initialise the object and then call `load()` then I'd extract those two functions into separate methods:

```
class Super(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self._initialise(*args, **kw)
        self.load()

    def _initialise(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def load(self):
        ... as before ...


class Sub(Super):
    def _initialise(self, arg2, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Sub, self)._initialise(*args, **kwargs)
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def load(self):
        super(Sub, self).load()
        ... as before ...
```

Now you have one `__init__()` that you *don't* override and you are no longer mixing the two separate operations of initialisation and loading together.

Comment: This is nice, works just as desired, but you lose the normal behavior of initializing in `__init__`. If you were going to use this method, you'd be better off customizing `Super.__new__` or `Super.__metaclass__` to rewrite `Sub.__init__` to `Sub._initialize` and a creating a wrapper `Super.__init__` to call `self._initialize`. This way subclasses could be written normally with `__init__` and it would all still "just work", as in my (slightly hackish) implementation.

Comment: I don't see a problem there; you've added constraints to how you want your `__init__` to work, so any subclass has to follow those constraints. You could also do what you suggested by doing the construction in a class method: that way you don't have to override `__new__` and the user creating the instance can choose whether or not to call `load()` automatically by calling something like `inst = Sub.create_and_load()`